# Convert text file to List<int>

Tags: c#, linq, list, csv, casting

I have a CSV file of ID numbers that I need as an `IEnumerable<int>`. I was trying to get from A to B as simply as possible, and came up with the following idea:

```
Global.migrated = File.ReadAllText(Global.migrationList).Split(',').Cast<int>().ToList<int>();
```

When I run this, though, I'm told that the Cast is invalid. I also tried reading to a String list and casting to int:

```
List<string> myTemp = File.ReadAllText(Global.migrationList).Split(',').ToList<string>();
Global.migrated = myTemp.Cast<int>();
```

But this raises the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.List.' An explicit conversion exists. Are you missing a cast?

I don't understand. The object I'm trying to cast isn't an `IEnumerable<int>` in this case. It should be a `List<string>`. I'm afraid I'm missing something important about how casting works.

Comment: `Cast<T>` returns `IEnumerable<T>`. You need to convert to list using `ToList()` extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the object, not cast it.

```
File.ReadAllText(Global.migrationList).Split(',')
   .Select(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
```

A cast is different from a convert in as much as the string value is a string, and not a number as far as the CLR is concerned. If the object being cast was a `float`, `decimal`, `double` or any numerical type then cast would work fine. But as the object is a `string` the CLR has no way to cast the object. You can, however, convert a `string` to an `integer` which actually parses the object and returns a new object rather than just converting its CLR type.

While you may think of casting and converting as being very similar in practical uses, they are very different things to the CLR

Comment: boxing unboxing issue?

Comment: @JP_medevice No, nothing here is boxed or unboxed.

Comment: then what is exact target of Convert.ToInt32? are those to convert saved strings?

Comment: @JP_medevice `Convert.ToInt32()` has a `string` overload, so that's the one that will be used.  However, even if the `object` overload were used, strings are references (not values) and so no boxing would occur.  Boxing only happens when you convert a value (something deriving `System.ValueType`) to a reference, as in `object x = 1;`.  That is not occurring here.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan! Worked great!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `Cast<int>()` on an enumerable of strings for the same reason you can't do `(int)"123"` -- there is no such implicit or explicit conversion operator between `string` and `int`.<sup>1</sup>

Just use `Select()`, passing the string elements through `int.Parse()`:

```
Global.migrated = File.ReadAllText(Global.migrationList)
                      .Split(',')
                      .Select(i => int.Parse(i))
                      .ToList();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, if there could be such a user-defined operator then it wouldn't be used here anyway.  Casts are resolved at compile-time, and generic types are substituted at runtime so user-defined conversion operators are not used when casting to or from generic types (except *possibly* when constraints are involved, as there is a certain amount of information that *can* be deduced at compile-time in that case).  But I digress.